# В Excel модальное окно не становиться активным?

Tags: c#, excel, vb.net

Есть Excel 2013 и для него add-in, написанный на c#.

Открываем два workbook в одном workspace. В workbook 1 по клику кнопки отображаем модальное диалоговое окно.

```
public void OnButtonRefreshWorkbook_Click(Office.IRibbonControl control)
{
    NativeWindow nativeWindow = GetCurrentActiveWindow();
    MessageBox.Show(nativeWindow, "Hello");
    nativeWindow.ReleaseHandle();
}
```

В результате оба ворбука блокируются, пока открыто это окно.

Но если перекрыть эти ворбуки с модальным диалоговым окном други окном (например Проводником), то при попытке в таскбаре виндуаса нажать на ворбук 2 не будет активировано и отображена модальное диалоговое окно, а отобразиться только ворбук 2, причём он будет заблокирован, т.е. не будет реагировать.

Для получения родительского окна перепробовал все варианты.
Вариант 1:

```
public NativeWindow GetCurrentActiveWindow()
{
    IntPtr handler = new IntPtr(this.Application.Hwnd);

    NativeWindow nativeWindow = new NativeWindow();
    nativeWindow.AssignHandle(handler);

    return nativeWindow;
}
```

Вариант 2:

```
public NativeWindow GetCurrentActiveWindow()
{
    IntPtr handler;

    using (var process = System.Diagnostics.Process.GetCurrentProcess())
    {
        handler = process.MainWindowHandle;
    }

    NativeWindow nativeWindow = new NativeWindow();
    nativeWindow.AssignHandle(handler);

    return nativeWindow;
}
```

Вариант 3:

```
public NativeWindow GetCurrentActiveWindow()
{
    IntPtr handler = new IntPtr(this.Application.ActiveWindow.Hwnd);

    NativeWindow nativeWindow = new NativeWindow();
    nativeWindow.AssignHandle(handler);

    return nativeWindow;
}
```

Но результат один и тот же. ворбук 2 отображается, а ворбук 1 с модальным диалогом нет.

Если посмотреть на Word или PowerPoint, то там четко, при попытке отобразить любое окно отображается модальное диалоговое окно.

Как бы такого же добиться в Excel?

Comment: а при чём vb.net?

Comment: @Anatol в основе вопрос про Add-In, написанный на .NET. А на VB.NET их много написано.